# How to solve a quadratic inequality that acts like a quadratic equality?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, polynomials, quadratics

This will be largely a trivial question.

But how do I solve an inequality like this: $3x^4 - 4x^2 + 1>0$ ?

 Of course, I can treat it like a quadratic inequality by saying $t=x^2$

So I can solve it like: $ 3t^2 - 4t +1 >0$

The solutions are: $t_1=1; t_2=\frac{1}{3}$

Or in termes of $x$: $x_1=1; x_2=-1; x_3=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{3}; x_4=-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{3}$

So if this were an *equality* then I had solved it as I found all the roots. 
But what does all this mean for *inequality*? 
How do I know where is this polynomial larger or smaller than $0$?

Comment: Your solutions of your quadratic are wrong, too, on multiple counts.  First of all, quadratic roots come in _pairs_; you can't have a (rational) quadratic with one root rational and the other irrational.  Secondly, all the coefficients of your quadratic are positive, so any real roots _have_ to be negative - if $t\geq 0$ then $t^2\geq 0$ and so $3t^2+4t+1\geq 1$.

Comment: You are right I corrected it. This is the quadratic I meant.

Comment: In general, factor the polynomial and then try to determine for what values of $x$ an even number of those factors is negative, as well as the values of $x$ that an odd number of those factors is negative.

Answer (score 2):

The inequality is trivial as you only have even powers, so

$$\forall\,x\in\Bbb R\;,\;\;x^4\ge0\;,\;\;x^2\ge 0\implies 3x^4+4x^2+1\ge 1>0$$

Answer (score 1):

**HINT:**

Since the product of the $4$ bracket expressions is positive, this implies that:

1. Either all the bracket expressions are positive

OR

2. Any two bracket expressions are positive and the other two are negative.

OR

3. All the bracket expressions are negative.